# Error saying "unable to update ICE authority" while booting

Tags: boot-failure

I often get an error saying

> unable to update ICE authority.

Is there a way out of this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's possible that you were using a graphical application running as root that has updated your ICE Authority file with root permissions.

Try the following in a terminal session:

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER .ICEauthority
sudo chmod 0644 .ICEauthority
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this was the cause of my issue, quoting bosniamaj

[Error '' could not update ICEauthority file'' and '' problem in configuration server''](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197746/error-could-not-update-iceauthority-file-and-problem-in-configuration-se/251576#251576?newreg=9ffc67b4871e47c4aaab66d4875e1a39)

I know it's been quite long when this question was submitted, but I had this problem today. I finally completely replaced my Win7 with Ubuntu 12.10 and this made me think about my decision.

But, after unsuccessfully trying many things I found on the internet, I found out with ls -l /home that the owner of my /home/username wasn't username:username but something else.

So, I changed it with sudo chown username:username /home/username, hit ctrl+alt+F7 to go back to the ordinary login screen and logged in successfully.

I hope this can help you too, or anyone else who faces similar problems.