# I can only log in as a guest how do i fix this

Tags: 11.10

i have just upgraded to ubuntu 11.10 i had to go into settings i dont know what i have done but now i can only log in as a guest when i boot up i get the message "can't update ICE authority file. /HOME/PAUL/ICEauthority"    Also when i try to get into the home folder i get "you dont have the authority to access this folder." what do i do to get into the home folder, i have the passsword but it wont give me permission as a guest but i cant log in as anyone else not even my own name

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error saying "unable to update ICE authority" while booting](http://askubuntu.com/questions/58877/error-saying-unable-to-update-ice-authority-while-booting)

Answer (score 4):

Since you mention that no user accounts work, you will need to reset the administrator password from recovery mode.  There is already an excellent Q&A describing this so I won't reiterate that here (see below).

When you have logged into the administrator account, you can reset the user ICE-Authority file as follows:

Open a terminal
`cd /home/[user account]`
where [user account] is the name of the account - for example `paul`

i.e. `cd /home/paul`

then

```
sudo chown paul:paul .ICEauthority
sudo chmod 0644 .ICEauthority
```

logout and then login to the `paul` account.

---

1. [Error saying "unable to update ICE authority" while booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58877/error-saying-unable-to-update-ice-authority-while-booting)
2. [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrativeroot-password)