# Error '' could not update ICEauthority file'' and '' problem in configuration server''

Tags: kernel

When I start my laptop and try to login, I'm facing these messages:

```
Could not find  ICEauthority
```

and

```
Problem with configuration server 
/use/lib/libgconf2-4/gconf-santy-check-2 exited with status 256.
```

After closing both error windows, if I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> the terminal window opens normally.

I Tried hardly but unable to solve these problems. If any one can, please help me.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been quite long when this question was submitted, but I had this problem today. I finally completely replaced my Win7 with Ubuntu 12.10 and this made me think about my decision.

But, after unsuccessfully trying many things I found on the internet, I found out with `ls -l /home` that the owner of my `/home/username` wasn't `username:username` but something else.

So, I changed it with `sudo chown username:username /home/username`, hit `ctrl+alt+F7` to go back to the ordinary login screen and logged in successfully.

I hope this can help you too, or anyone else who faces similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen the old "ICEauthority" problem pop up for a while - I had to think what it was.  This problem normally occurs when someone restores all or part of their home directory from backups, but uses sudo or root to do so.  Since they used root privileges to do the copy the file owned by root and their user does not have access to create or change the ICE (Inter-Client Exchange) authority file.  Some people have also reported that installing some server type applications has caused the same problem.

Check that you can create new files in your home directory and check the ownership of the .ICE authority file:

```
ls -l .ICEauthority
```

If the owner of this file is root:root you can change it with chown:

```
sudo chown user:user ~/.ICEauthority
```

change user to your username.

If this still fails you can try removing the .ICEauthority file, but you might feel safer moving it rather than just deleting it:

```
mv .ICEauthority ICEbkup
```

I can't help with the gconf-santy-check-2 problem; it doesn't even exist on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
On the login page go to terminal by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

Login as root 
   for this :

```
#su root
password :*********** (Give your root password here)
```

Go to home directory :

```
#cd /home (This directory contains all user's HOME directories)
```

Change permission for your HOME directory.

```
#chmod 755 /home/your_home_directory
```

Reboot :

```
#reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo chown "usuario" /home/"usuario"/.ICEauthority
```

- cambiar "usuario" por tu nombre de usuario por ejemplo en mi caso "tony":
  ~$"sudo chown tony /home/tony/.ICEauthority"
  A continuación reiniciar el sistema:
  ~$ sudo reboot